# Install only docker client/cli binaries on centos

Tags: centos, docker

Is it possible to install the docker client/cli binaries *only* - i.e. without the deamon?

I currently install docker-ce on centos using `yum install docker-ce`, as detailed [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce-1).

However I can't find a package that only contains the client binaries. I need to keep my image as small as possible so don't want to install the deamon when I'm never going to use it.

There is some information around suggesting that you can extract the relevant binaries from the main docker-ce package, but I'd really like to know if there is a more supported/maintainable way to do this (ideally via yum if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate package for just the CLI yet. It has been [requested before](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/15360) and any new request should be directed to the appropriate platform specific repo, e.g. [docker/for-linux](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues).

While it does add an extra 100MB or so, the easiest solution is to still install the full engine and just not enable the service.

The less maintainable option is to manually pull the [statically compiled binaries](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/), and extract only the client specific files you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, statically linked CLI binaries are available here, but you have to unpack the tarball and keep just the files you want, e.g. `docker`.

https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/